# I need to add view badges to the cart shopping button

Tags: java, android

My question about shopping button view Badges. I want to add badges to the shopping button.All the codes that I read were about adding the button and its notifications to the menu and the action bar and I do not want to add the button to the menu. The application was I created by Navigation Drawer activity. This activity automatically creates a ready button to give it anything you want. And this code for the button and badges that I have added to it, but I want the code for these badges, but outside the action bar

```
 <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:contextClickable="true"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_add_shopping_cart_white_48dp"
    app:useCompatPadding="true"
    tools:targetApi="m" />
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="48dp"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
    tools:ignore="RtlHardcoded">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/badge_textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="10"
        android:paddingEnd="8dp"
        android:paddingRight="8dp"
        android:paddingLeft="8dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="#FFF"
        android:textSize="11sp"
        android:background="@drawable/badge_circle"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

and This code of command the button "fab" in the main activity

```
private static final int ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE = 6 ;
private static final int ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE2 = 3 ;
private static final int ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE3 = 4 ;
private static final int ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE4 = 5 ;
String sandwish;
int sandwishI;
String snack;
int snackI;
String juice;
int juiceI;
String pizza;
int pizzaI;

 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate( savedInstanceState );
    setContentView( R.layout.activity_main );

    final FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById( R.id.fab );
    fab.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
Intent i = new Intent( MainActivity.this, Order.class );
            Bundle b = new Bundle();
            b.putString("string", sandwish);
            b.putString("name",snack );
            b.putString("value1", juice);
            b.putString("value2",pizza );
            b.putInt( "INT",sandwishI );
            b.putInt( "INT1",snackI );
            b.putInt( "INT2",juiceI );
            b.putInt( "INT3",pizzaI );
            i.putExtra("personBdl", b);
            startActivity( i );
        }
    } );
 @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if ((resultCode == RESULT_OK) && (requestCode == ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE)) {
        sandwish = data.getExtras().getString( Sandwish.REG_NAME_TAG );
        sandwishI = data.getExtras().getInt( Sandwish.REG_INT_TAG );
    }
    if ((resultCode == RESULT_OK) && (requestCode == ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE2)) {
        snack = data.getExtras().getString( Snacks.REG_NAME_TAG);
        snackI = data.getExtras().getInt( Snacks.REG_INT_TAG );
    }
    if ((resultCode == RESULT_OK) && (requestCode == ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE3)) {
        juice = data.getExtras().getString( Juices.REG_NAME_TAG );
        juiceI = data.getExtras().getInt( Juices.REG_INT_TAG );
    }
    if ((resultCode == RESULT_OK) && (requestCode == ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE4)) {
        pizza = data.getExtras().getString( Pizza.REG_NAME_TAG );
        pizzaI = data.getExtras().getInt( Pizza.REG_INT_TAG );
    }
}
```

The codes in the main activity are to import string and int values from several other activities and the button "fab" send them all to another new activity that displays these values in full.
this is an example of a value imported from an activity

```
 public void submitOrder(View view) {
    // find the user's name
    CheckBox txt1CheckBox = (CheckBox) findViewById( R.id.txt1 );
    boolean hasTxt1 = txt1CheckBox.isChecked();

    CheckBox txt11CheckBox = (CheckBox) findViewById( R.id.txt11 );
    boolean hasTxt11 = txt11CheckBox.isChecked();

    boolean isTxt1 = true;
    if (isTxt1) {
    } else {
    }
    boolean isTxt11 = true;
    if (isTxt11) {
    } else {
    }
   String text = "";
    if(txt1CheckBox.isChecked()) {
        text += "\n" + "(" + quantity1 + ")" + "    " + getString( R.string.submit_order_hamburger );
    }
    if(txt11CheckBox.isChecked()) {
        text += "\n" + "(" + quantity2 + ")" + "    " + getString( R.string.submit_order_Cheese_burger );
    }
          
    Intent i = new Intent();
    i.putExtra(REG_NAME_TAG, text);
    i.putExtra( REG_INT_TAG, price );
    setResult(RESULT_OK,i);
    finish();
}

private int calculatePrice(boolean hasTxt1, boolean hasTxt11, boolean hasTxt111, boolean hasTxt1111, boolean hasTxt11111) {
    int mprice = 0;
    if (hasTxt1) {
        mprice = mprice + 500 * quantity1;
    }
    if (hasTxt11) {
        mprice = mprice + 600 * quantity2;
    }               
    return mprice;
}
```

This is a picture of the button and its location in the main activity of the application

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> **Use this widget by replacing `FloatingActionButton`**

```
public class FabForCart extends FloatingActionButton {

    private final Property<FabForCart, Float> ANIMATION_PROPERTY =
            new Property<FabForCart, Float>(Float.class, "animation") {

                @Override
                public void set(FabForCart object, Float value) {
                    mAnimationFactor = value;
                    postInvalidateOnAnimation();
                }

                @Override
                public Float get(FabForCart object) {
                    return 0f;
                }
            };

    private static final int MAX_COUNT = 99;
    private static final String MAX_COUNT_TEXT = "99+";
    private static final int TEXT_SIZE_DP = 11;
    private static final int TEXT_PADDING_DP = 2;
    private static final int MASK_COLOR = Color.parseColor("#33000000"); // Translucent black as mask color
    private static final Interpolator ANIMATION_INTERPOLATOR = new OvershootInterpolator();

    private final Rect mContentBounds;
    private final Paint mTextPaint;
    private final float mTextSize;
    private final Paint mCirclePaint;
    private final Rect mCircleBounds;
    private final Paint mMaskPaint;
    private final int mAnimationDuration;
    private float mAnimationFactor;

    private int mCount;
    private String mText;
    private float mTextHeight;
    private ObjectAnimator mAnimator;

    public FabForCart(Context context) {
        this(context, null, 0);
    }

    public FabForCart(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context, attrs, 0);
    }

    public FabForCart(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        setUseCompatPadding(true);

        final float density = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;

        mTextSize = TEXT_SIZE_DP * density;
        float textPadding = TEXT_PADDING_DP * density;

        mAnimationDuration = getResources().getInteger(android.R.integer.config_shortAnimTime);
        mAnimationFactor = 1;

        mTextPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        mTextPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        mTextPaint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        mTextPaint.setTextSize(mTextSize);
        mTextPaint.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.CENTER);
        mTextPaint.setTypeface(Typeface.SANS_SERIF);

        mCirclePaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        mCirclePaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        ColorStateList colorStateList = getBackgroundTintList();
        if (colorStateList != null) {
            mCirclePaint.setColor(colorStateList.getDefaultColor());
        } else {
            Drawable background = getBackground();
            if (background instanceof ColorDrawable) {
                ColorDrawable colorDrawable = (ColorDrawable) background;
                mCirclePaint.setColor(colorDrawable.getColor());
            }
        }

        mMaskPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        mMaskPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        mMaskPaint.setColor(MASK_COLOR);

        Rect textBounds = new Rect();
        mTextPaint.getTextBounds(MAX_COUNT_TEXT, 0, MAX_COUNT_TEXT.length(), textBounds);
        mTextHeight = textBounds.height();

        float textWidth = mTextPaint.measureText(MAX_COUNT_TEXT);
        float circleRadius = Math.max(textWidth, mTextHeight) / 2f + textPadding;
        mCircleBounds = new Rect(0, 0, (int) (circleRadius * 2), (int) (circleRadius * 2));
        mContentBounds = new Rect();

        onCountChanged();
    }

    /**
     * @return The current count value
     */
    public int getCount() {
        return mCount;
    }

    /**
     * Set the count to show on badge
     *
     * @param count The count value starting from 0
     */
    public void setCount(@IntRange(from = 0) int count) {
        if (count == mCount) return;
        mCount = count > 0 ? count : 0;
        onCountChanged();
        if (ViewCompat.isLaidOut(this)) {
            startAnimation();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Increase the current count value by 1
     */
    public void increase() {
        setCount(mCount + 1);
    }

    /**
     * Decrease the current count value by 1
     */
    public void decrease() {
        setCount(mCount > 0 ? mCount - 1 : 0);
    }

    private void onCountChanged() {
        if (mCount > MAX_COUNT) {
            mText = String.valueOf(MAX_COUNT_TEXT);
        } else {
            mText = String.valueOf(mCount);
        }
    }

    private void startAnimation() {
        float start = 0f;
        float end = 1f;
        if (mCount == 0) {
            start = 1f;
            end = 0f;
        }
        if (isAnimating()) {
            mAnimator.cancel();
        }
        mAnimator = ObjectAnimator.ofObject(this, ANIMATION_PROPERTY, null, start, end);
        mAnimator.setInterpolator(ANIMATION_INTERPOLATOR);
        mAnimator.setDuration(mAnimationDuration);
        mAnimator.start();
    }

    private boolean isAnimating() {
        return mAnimator != null && mAnimator.isRunning();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        if (mCount > 0 || isAnimating()) {
            if (getContentRect(mContentBounds)) {
                mCircleBounds.offsetTo(mContentBounds.left + mContentBounds.width() - mCircleBounds.width(), mContentBounds.top);
            }
            float cx = mCircleBounds.centerX();
            float cy = mCircleBounds.centerY();
            float radius = mCircleBounds.width() / 2f * mAnimationFactor;
            // Solid circle
            canvas.drawCircle(cx, cy, radius, mCirclePaint);
            // Mask circle
            canvas.drawCircle(cx, cy, radius, mMaskPaint);
            // Count text
            mTextPaint.setTextSize(mTextSize * mAnimationFactor);
            canvas.drawText(mText, cx, cy + mTextHeight / 2f, mTextPaint);
        }
    }

    private static class SavedState extends View.BaseSavedState {

        private int count;

        /**
         * Constructor called from {@link FabForCart#onSaveInstanceState()}
         */
        private SavedState(Parcelable superState) {
            super(superState);
        }

        /**
         * Constructor called from {@link #CREATOR}
         */
        private SavedState(Parcel in) {
            super(in);
            count = in.readInt();
        }

        @Override
        public void writeToParcel(Parcel out, int flags) {
            super.writeToParcel(out, flags);
            out.writeInt(count);
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return FabForCart.class.getSimpleName() + "." + SavedState.class.getSimpleName() + "{"
                    + Integer.toHexString(System.identityHashCode(this))
                    + " count=" + count + "}";
        }

        public static final Creator<SavedState> CREATOR
                = new Creator<SavedState>() {
            public SavedState createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
                return new SavedState(in);
            }

            public SavedState[] newArray(int size) {
                return new SavedState[size];
            }
        };
    }

    @Override
    public Parcelable onSaveInstanceState() {
        Parcelable superState = super.onSaveInstanceState();
        SavedState ss = new SavedState(superState);
        ss.count = mCount;
        return ss;
    }

    @Override
    public void onRestoreInstanceState(Parcelable state) {
        SavedState ss = (SavedState) state;
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(ss.getSuperState());
        setCount(ss.count);
        requestLayout();
    }

}
```

> **XML code**

```
<com.yourpackage.widgets.FabForCart
     android:id="@+id/fabCart"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
     android:layout_margin="@dimen/_12sdp"
     android:gravity="center"
     app:fabSize="normal"
     app:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
     app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|left"
     app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_vector_shoping_cart_white" />
```

> **Write this in your Java File for setting badgeCount**

`fabCart.setCount(10); // set your count value from here`